# Why can Twitter API Authorization data be sent through GET or POST params instead of HTTP headers?

Tags: ajax, oauth, http-headers, twitter

I'm using oauth.js and sha1.js in a Greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        twitter_api
// @namespace   twitter
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @require http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js
// @require http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha1.js
// ==/UserScript==

var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
var accessor = {
  token: "XXX",
  tokenSecret: "XXX",
  consumerKey : "XXX",
  consumerSecret: "XXX"
};
var message = {
  action: url,
  method: "POST",
  parameters: {status: "apitest"}
};
OAuth.completeRequest(message, accessor);
OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);
var authorization = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" + encodeURIComponent(OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters).oauth_consumer_key) + "\""
            + ", oauth_nonce=\"" + encodeURIComponent(OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters).oauth_nonce) + "\""
            + ", oauth_signature=\"" + encodeURIComponent(OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters).oauth_signature) + "\""
            + ", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\""
            + ", oauth_timestamp=\"" + encodeURIComponent(OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters).oauth_timestamp) + "\""
            + ", oauth_token=\"" + encodeURIComponent(OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters).oauth_token) + "\""
            + ", oauth_version=\"1.0\"";
```

Using Authorization header with POST request:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: "status=apitest",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": authorization
  },
  onload: function(response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
  }
});
```

Using GET params only with POST request:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: url + '?' + OAuth.formEncode(message.parameters),
  onload: function(response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
  }
});
```

Using POST params only with POST request:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: OAuth.formEncode(message.parameters),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  onload: function(response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
  }
});
```

Why do this 3 AJAX requests work when Twitter clearly says you have to send an Authorization header?
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request

If both GET, POST, HTTP header Authorization are accepted, why should I prefer HTTP header, is it more secure or maybe it doesn't matter since it's an API call?